# printing multiple integers at the same time

Tags: c, printf

I was wondering if there is a better way to print an array of ints in c;

At the moment I do a `printf("%d" ,.. )`  for every int in my array.

However this causes one system call per int? (if my understanding is correct).

It would be better to convert the int array to string buffer and then print the buffer in one call.

I can write the code for it if necessary.

Q1. is this a good idea or too much hassle to be worth it?

Q2. Are there any libraries that implement such a thing. (Whatever I google comes back to beginners tutorials for printing integers :s)

**Edit**
The size of the array is not known before hand.

Comment: printf("%d %d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1],arr[2]) makes one write() call - at most -  the system call you are worried about.

Comment: @jimmcnamara array is of dynamic size.. so cant hard code it in this way. I have updated the question.

Comment: You were asking about working around a "multiple" system call scenario.  Not a programming workaround, IMO.

Comment: "if my understanding is correct" -- 9 out of 10 times, when beginners say this, it's false.

Comment: @JimBalter quite true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `printf`, the output is already buffered. The system call is made only when you "flush" the buffer - either explicitly by calling `fflush(stdout)` or implicitly by printing `\n` to a console. Therefore, pre-buffering on the application side will make your code more complex without offering any real difference in performance.

As far as a library to help you write `int`s to a string goes, you can use the same `<stdio.h>` that you are already using: allocate a buffer sufficiently large to hold your integers, use `sprintf` instead of `printf` to write to it, and then call `printf` with the content of the entire buffer. This would help you avoid flushing on `\n`, should you decide to use them as separators in your output.

Comment: thanks. If it is buffered then I guess I can just use printf. although sprintf is a good idea.

Comment: @OsamaJaved The only case when `sprintf` would be useful is if you wanted to use `\n` as a separator, *and* you wanted to write to an output stream associated with console (file output streams do not get flushed on `\n` anyway).

Comment: You've omitted unbuffered streams -- stdout can be made unbuffered, just as stderr is by default.

Comment: @JimBalter That's an interesting observation. Can one make `stdout` unbuffered from outside the program, say, through some environment configuration parameters?

Comment: Perhaps in some implementation somewhere, but normally stdio sets it line buffered or buffered, depending on whether it's a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not cause one system call per `int`, unless you set `stdout` to unbuffered mode. This is the whole point of stdio: to buffer output for you so you don't have to do it yourself. There is a minimal amount of additional *call overhead* for the `printf` function itself. If you find yourself needing more performance, you could try something like:

```
for (i=0; i+4<=N; i+=4)
    printf("%d %d %d %d ", a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2], a[i+3]);
for (; i<N; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
```

Comment: if its buffered I dont need to worry at all then :D. Thanks